# Beautiful soup gives an empty output

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a div whose id is "123".

[The content is like this;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF36G.png)

The code I use is;

```
a = soup.find_all("div",{"id":"123"})
```

when i use this code [i get this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A8Uq.png)

So it gives an output, but it's empty. It shows up as "[]"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. Right now the best anyone can possibly tell you is "the HTML doesn't contain what you expect it to contain". It's impossible to be more specific, because we don't have a small, reproducible example of the HTML content that causes the problem. A picture like that is not sufficient to prove that `soup.find_all("div",{"id":"123"})` should actually find anything. Especially consider the possibility that the `div` in question is created, or its ID assigned, dynamically by Javascript. BeautifulSoup cannot handle that; it **only** reads HTML.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add any needed additional information; and [please do not use images to show output](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - instead, copy and paste the text, formatted like code. Instead of showing an image of the web page, try showing a fragment of HTML from the page that you expect to give a different result from the actual result. (Make sure that the `soup` actually contains that HTML.)

Answer (score 0):

try using find_all like this

```
soup.find_all('div', id="123")
```

Here is the documentation of find_all in Beautiful Soup for more reference [link](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=find_all#find-all)

Or there is a chance that there is no div with id "123"